# No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver. C3P0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am trying to upload images(one by one) using c3p0 connection pooling but my jdbc type 4 driver(connecting to mysql) keeps on closing the connection. I have seen that the maximum timeout in the configuration of mysql is set to 300 seconds. Here is how my persistence xml uses c3p0.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    scope="singleton" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="...." />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="...." />
    <property name="user" value="....." />
    <property name="password" value="...." />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="5" />
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Can someone explain what exactly is causing the driver to implicitly close the connection.
Also, how can i reolve this issue?

Here is the error message I get:

```
19:01:45,504  WARN NewPooledConnection:486 - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!

19:01:45,505  WARN NewPooledConnection:487 - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver. ] which will not be reported to listeners!

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
```

Comment: I think this question is more for [superuser](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: @PlasmaPower, it's pretty much belongs here.

Comment: @Reddy This is about drivers, the only code here is XML. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that questions should be about: a specific **programming** problem (no), a software algorithm (no), software tools commonly used by programmers (sorta, but this is a driver error), or practical, answerable problems that are unique to **software** development (no). [Super users's help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) says questions should be about: computer hardware, computer software (applies here), or personal and home computer networking.

Comment: @PlasmaPower, how did u come to conclusion that it's driver problem and not XML configuration problem? or something else? If you think XML is not the way to be here, Spring/Hibernate or many frameworks, questions are related to XML configuration. Please mark it for Moderation if you feel not right.

Comment: @user3458148, did you try the below answer

Comment: @Reddy OK, I see your point. It seemed like it was a driver problem based on the error messages (it was **implicitly** closed by the driver).

Comment: Key logging message is _"A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!"_ Some classes of errors will make the connection pool close and revoke the logical connection and close the physical connection as it is no longer usable. Your application continues using the connection after that error (that or the error class / sql state is 'wrong', or the connection pool considers too many classes of errors as fatal for the connection).

Comment: Hi Mark and Reddy,
Thanks for answering the issue. 
Reddy: maxIdleTime solution doesnt seem to resolve the issue.
@Mark: Please suggest what I can do as the same code workd fine on my machine but not on Production server.

Comment: is there no error earlier in your logs? according to c3p0, the Connection encountered an earlier error (which the pool considered fatal; this Connection will be destroyed rather than reused on check-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change this to

```
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="0" />  //0 = never expire
```

Comment: Even though my issue is not resolved,for the problem I had asked, this  is the most appropriate solution. Maybe I have some other issues also and that's why my error persists.